# Getting error: “Ignoring exception in command play” when running my hangman game for - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have created a hangman command but upon calling the command in Discord, it gave an error as shown in the second code. Would anyone happen to know what this error is referring to, or something wrong in my current code?

```
    @bot.command()
    async def hangman(self, ctx):
        """Play hangman!"""
        game = Hangman(ctx, self.bot)
        await game.play()
```

```
Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 851, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 786, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 542, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing.
```

for the code of the hangman class, here it is for more details because i really dont know where the problem is since ive already labeled `self.ctx = ctx` so im really confused how to solve the problem

```
class Hangman():
    """Play Hangman!"""
    def __init__(self, ctx, bot):
        # setting up bot and context
        self.ctx = ctx
        self.bot = bot

        # setting up game
        self.word = RandomWords().random_word().upper()
        self.guessed = {'words':[], 'letters':[]}
        self.success = False
        self.progress = '_' * len(self.word)
        self.tries = 6

        # misc
        self.started = False
        self.gameOver = {
            True: 'Congrats! You win!',
            False: f'Sorry, you ran out of tries, **{self.word}** was the word'
        }

        global stages
        self.stages = stages

    async def play(self):
        """Use this command to play hangman"""

        # play the game

        msg = await self.ctx.send(f'Game starts now! Your word is {len(self.word)} letters long!')
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

        while self.tries > 0 and not self.success:

            await msg.edit(content='Guess a letter or word!')

            try:
                guess = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.author == self.ctx.author and m.channel == self.ctx.channel, timeout=60)

            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                msg = await msg.edit(content='Game over, you took to long to guess')
                await asyncio.sleep(5)
                await msg.delete()
                return

            reply = guess
            guess = guess.content.upper()

            if len(guess) == 1 and guess.isalpha():
                if guess in self.guessed['letters']:
                    await msg.edit(content='You have already guessed the letter!')
                    await asyncio.sleep(1.5)

                elif not guess in self.word:
                    self.guessed['letters'].append(guess)
                    self.tries -= 1
                    await msg.edit(content='You have guessed the wrong letter')
                    await asyncio.sleep(1.5)

                else:
                    indices = [index for index, letter in enumerate(self.word) if letter == guess]
                    self.progress = list(self.progress)
                    for i in indices:
                        self.progress[i] = guess

                    self.progress = "".join(self.progress)

                    self.guessed['letters'].append(guess)
                    await msg.edit(content='You have guessed the right letter!')
                    await asyncio.sleep(1.5)

                    if self.word == self.progress: self.success = True

            elif len(guess) == len(self.word) and guess.isalpha():
                if guess == self.word:
                    self.success = True

                else:
                    self.guessed['words'].append(guess)
                    await msg.edit(content="You haven't guessed the right word")
                    await asyncio.sleep(1.5)

            else:
                await msg.edit(content='Your reply doesn\'t make sense')
                await asyncio.sleep(1.5)

            if self.started == True:
                await gameplay.edit(content=f'`{self.progress}`\n\n{self.stages[self.tries]}\n\nChances left: {self.tries}')

            else:
                gameplay = await self.ctx.send(f'`{self.progress}`\n\n{self.stages[self.tries]}\n\nChances left: {self.tries}')
                self.started = True

            await reply.delete()

        await self.ctx.send(self.gameOver[self.success])
```

also keep in mind that im pretty new to discord.py and python itself and many of these codes are copied so please be easy on me

Comment: Is this bot.command() within a class somehow? It seems you are trying to use the specific commands.ext functionality in a way it isnt intended. You should be defining commands at base level with ctx as first argument as far as i know. (the problem might not be in the Hangman class and you dont quite give enough context for the @bot.command()

Answer (score 0):

Your `hangman` coroutine shouldn't be expecting a `self` argument, only `ctx`. You're getting this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing.
```

Because when you call your `hangman` **command** in Discord with no arguments, `discord.py` is calling your `hangman` **coroutine** with only a single [`Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#context) argument. Since you've defined the coroutine to accept two mandatory arguments, the `Context` object gets bound to `self`, but there's no other argument to bind to your `ctx` parameter, hence the "`ctx` is a required argument that is missing" in your error message.

You don't show us where you've defined your `hangman` coroutine, but it shouldn't be taking a `self` parameter; just remove it.

```
@bot.command()
async def hangman(ctx):
    """Play hangman!"""
    game = Hangman(ctx, self.bot)
    await game.play()
```